# Adding multilabel classifier to TensorFlow example

Tags: classification, tensorflow, image-classification, image-recognition, labels

I am starting with the generic TensorFlow example.

To classify my data I need to use multiple labels (ideally multiple `softmax` classifiers) on the final layer, because my data carries multiple independent labels (sum of probabilities is not 1).

Specifically in the `retrain.py` these lines in `add_final_training_ops()` add the final tensor

```
final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
```

and here

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      logits, ground_truth_input)
```

Is there already a generic classifier in TensorFlow? If not, how to achieve multilevel classification?

`add_final_training_ops()` from `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py`:

```
def add_final_training_ops(class_count, final_tensor_name, bottleneck_tensor):

  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    bottleneck_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        bottleneck_tensor, shape=[None, BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE],
        name='BottleneckInputPlaceholder')

    ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        [None, class_count],
                                        name='GroundTruthInput')

  layer_name = 'final_training_ops'
  with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
      layer_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, class_count], stddev=0.001), name='final_weights')
      variable_summaries(layer_weights)
    with tf.name_scope('biases'):
      layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
      variable_summaries(layer_biases)
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, layer_weights) + layer_biases
      tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', logits)

  final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
  tf.summary.histogram('activations', final_tensor)

  with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      logits, ground_truth_input)
    with tf.name_scope('total'):
      cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
  tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy_mean)

  with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(
        cross_entropy_mean)

  return (train_step, cross_entropy_mean, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input,
          final_tensor)
```

Even after adding the `sigmoid` classifier and retraining, Tensorboard still shows `softmax`:

[image: Tensorboard with softmax]

Comment: Are all the labels in your data independent classes, or is there a mix where some groups are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If all classes are exclusive, then you can just use softmax. Saying "all classes are exclusive" is same as saying "class probabilities sum to 1". Saying "all classes are independent" is the opposite.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that I have independent classes that are  used based on the outcome of the softmax classifier. In my data there is a mix of 3 mutually exclusive groups of classes. Based on the result of this softmax classification, certain classes will be used from a poll of independent classes. For simplification of this question, you may assume all classes are independent.

Comment: If all classes are independent, then you can use sigmoid activation in output layer to represent the class probabilities. So for a simplified approach you can just swap softmax for sigmoid. There is even a [sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) function so the example can be adapted very easily. Dealing with the hierarchical class memberships would be more complex.  Your question looks a bit messy BTW, it is not clear why you have pasted all that code from the examples?

Comment: I removed some of the code, because I am wondering where to switch from `softmax` to `sigmoid`. Simply using `final_tensor = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits, name=final_tensor_name)` and
`cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
          logits, ground_truth_input)` does not change the classifier. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I was going to suggest. I am not sure what else could be wrong/different. Maybe someone else will spot something. If the problem is that this is not training well, you may need to look at one or more of choice of optimiser, choice of hyper-params, such as learning rate, size/number of layers etc. Also, you don't show what metrics you are using (other than reporting mean log loss) - your metrics will likely need to change to report on multiple classes, in case you were using accuracy metric before . . .

Comment: Yes, I am taking the example code as it is and trying to spot what needs to be changed. Tensorboard still shows `pool_3` layer connected to `softmax` in the graph visualization tab, even after doing the classifier change. Calling `bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image` also results in output of the `softmax` classifier (percentages with sum=1). This all shows that the classifier is still `softmax` and not `sigmoid`.

Comment: I don't use TensorBoard much, but would suspect some mismatch between what you are viewing there and the code you have modified. Maybe a caching or naming issue?